# Ejecutar evento solamente de la clase seleccionada con Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola quisiera ejecutar evento depende del div que le de click.

Yo estoy probando este código pero cuando lo hago, se ejecutan en todos y solo quiero en el que le doy click.

Lo que básicamente lo que hace este evento es que cuando le doy a ver precio, se oculte ese texto y aparezca el precio, y lo que quiero es que se ejecute solamente al que le doy, y no a todos.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
        .preciomax{ display:none; }
    </style>

    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".btnvp").click(function(evento){
                    $(".btnver").css("display", "none");
                    $(".preciomax").css("display", "contents");
                });
            });
    </script>

    <div class="row cntrpct mb-4 mr-0 ml-0">
      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="crdpdt">
            <img alt="" class="img-fluid imgscale" src="https://perudigital.net.pe/adm_tienda/consultas/img1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 footprodc">
          <a href="detalle-producto?Id_Producto=1"><img src="img/recursos/ver_tienda.png" width="35"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 cldprice mb-3">
        <h5>Descripción</h5>
        <h4>Producto 1</h4>
        <p class="text-dark">Este es un producto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
        <div class="mt-4">
          <h5>Por menor: S/.16</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2">
          <h5>Por mayor: <span class="btnver"> <button type="button" class="btnvp">Ver Precio</button> </span> <span class="preciomax"> S/.13 </span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-4">
          <a href="detalle-producto?Id_Producto=1" class="btn btn-producto">VER PRODUCTO</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cntrpct mb-4 mr-0 ml-0">
      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="crdpdt">
            <img alt="" class="img-fluid imgscale" src="https://perudigital.net.pe/adm_tienda/consultas/img2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 footprodc">
          <a href="detalle-producto?Id_Producto=2"><img src="img/recursos/ver_tienda.png" width="35"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 cldprice mb-3">
        <h5>Descripción</h5>
        <h4>Producto 2</h4>
        <p class="text-dark">Este es un producto 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
        <div class="mt-4">
          <h5>Por menor: S/.15</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2">
          <h5>Por mayor: <span class="btnver"> <button type="button" class="btnvp">Ver Precio</button> </span> <span class="preciomax"> S/.10 </span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-4">
          <a href="detalle-producto?Id_Producto=2" class="btn btn-producto">VER PRODUCTO</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Espero se me entienda y me ayuden.

Comment: hazlo agrgando la propiedad onclick en la etiqueta html que desees que se ejecute, puedes mandarle el objecto por medio de this en la funcion de javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del `this`, que hace referencia a diferentes cosas dependiendo del contexto desde donde lo llames.

En el caso de los eventos de **JQuery**, `$(this)` hace referencia al elemento que está disparando el evento. De esta manera puedes referenciar, de todos los elementos de una clase, al único que se esté haciendo **click** en ese momento.

Una vez capturado el elemento, puedes acceder al padre más cercano de ambos elementos a los que quieres afectar (en tu caso el `<h5>`) y después buscarlos dentro del padre para afectar solamente a los relacionados con el botón que estás pulsando.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .preciomax{ display:none; }
</style>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".btnvp").click(function(evento) {
                let elemento = $(this);
                let padre = elemento.parents('h5');
                
                padre.find(".btnver").css("display", "none");
                padre.find(".preciomax").css("display", "contents");
            });
        });
</script>


<div class="row cntrpct mb-4 mr-0 ml-0">
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="crdpdt">
        <img alt="" class="img-fluid imgscale" src="https://perudigital.net.pe/adm_tienda/consultas/img1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3 footprodc">
      <a href="detalle-producto?Id_Producto=1"><img src="img/recursos/ver_tienda.png" width="35"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 cldprice mb-3">
    <h5>Descripción</h5>
    <h4>Producto 1</h4>
    <p class="text-dark">Este es un producto</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="mt-4">
      <h5>Por menor: S/.16</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-2">
      <h5>Por mayor: <span class="btnver"> <button type="button" class="btnvp">Ver Precio</button> </span> <span class="preciomax"> S/.13 </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4">
      <a href="detalle-producto?Id_Producto=1" class="btn btn-producto">VER PRODUCTO</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row cntrpct mb-4 mr-0 ml-0">
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="crdpdt">
        <img alt="" class="img-fluid imgscale" src="https://perudigital.net.pe/adm_tienda/consultas/img2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3 footprodc">
      <a href="detalle-producto?Id_Producto=2"><img src="img/recursos/ver_tienda.png" width="35"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 cldprice mb-3">
    <h5>Descripción</h5>
    <h4>Producto 2</h4>
    <p class="text-dark">Este es un producto 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="mt-4">
      <h5>Por menor: S/.15</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-2">
      <h5>Por mayor: <span class="btnver"> <button type="button" class="btnvp">Ver Precio</button> </span> <span class="preciomax"> S/.10 </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4">
      <a href="detalle-producto?Id_Producto=2" class="btn btn-producto">VER PRODUCTO</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quedo perfecto, muchas gracias! Una nueva skill el día de hoy.